# Optimize a Date and Timespan function

Tags: optimization, performance, datetime, vb.net

I have a working function that may be optimizable.

Currently processing 4 objects gives me `0.0459822` for the elapsed time in seconds - used for testing purposes. Once implemented into the app I will be checking > 1000 objects at a time and would like to speed this up if possible. The format of the `fd.dataTime` and the other `TimeSpans` are from a database and I have no control over the format. The reason for adding a day to some Dates is due to the time going over midnight and would yield an incorrect minimum timespan as a result.

Required: manually adding a day to the date if the time is less than the date - only case is presented below(before midnight date - after midnight timespans). Only store valid timespans. `nullField` is a `String` that = `0:00:00` an empty `TimeSpan` found in DB.

Here is the Function:

```
Private Function GetMinTimeSpan(fds As List(Of Field)) As String
 Dim result As New List(Of Date)
 For Each fd In fds
  Dim dt As Date = fd.dateTime
  Dim s1 As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(dt.ToString("HH:mm:ss"))
  Dim s2 As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(fd.sg)
  Dim s3 As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(fd.os)
  If Not fd.sg = nullField Then
    If s1 > s2 Then
      result.Add(Date.Parse(dt.AddDays(1).ToShortDateString & " " & fd.sg))
    Else
      result.Add(Date.Parse(dt.ToShortDateString & " " & fd.sg))
    End If
  End If
  If s1 > s3 Then
    result.Add(Date.Parse(dt.AddDays(1).ToShortDateString & " " & fd.os))
  Else
    result.Add(Date.Parse(dt.ToShortDateString & " " & fd.os))
  End If
 Next
 Return result.Min.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
End Function
```

Here is a sample testing:

```
Dim sw As New Stopwatch
sw.Start()
Dim fd1 As New Field With {.dateTime = Date.Now, .sg = "23:59:00", .os = "00:03:00"}
Dim fd2 As New Field With {.dateTime = Date.Now, .sg = "00:01:00", .os = "00:03:00"}
Dim fd3 As New Field With {.dateTime = Date.Now, .sg = "0:00:00", .os = "00:04:00"}
Dim fd4 As New Field With {.dateTime = Date.Now, .sg = "00:12:00", .os = "00:05:00"}
Dim fds As New List(Of Field) From {fd1, fd2, fd3, fd4}
Dim m = GetMinTimeSpan(fds)
Debug.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.ToString)
```

Comment: The `StopWatch` is running when you are declaring the variables in your sample - Is this intended?

Answer (score 15):

I'm not sure how to optimize your code, but let's talk about those variable names.

Naming is *hard*. It's doubly hard in vb.net, because it's case insensitive. That fact makes it difficult not to step on keywords like `Field`. I don't like recommending this, but without a being able to use `fields` and `field` to differentiate from the keywords `Fields` and `Field`, you could de-vowel it to `flds` and `fld` and still have a variable name that's easier to understand than `fd`.

`dt` I get, but what does that date actually represent?

`s1`,`s2`,`s3`? What do those mean? I vaguely understand what `s1` is, but then I hit this.

```
Dim s2 As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(fd.sg)
Dim s3 As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(fd.os)
```

`Field.sg` and `Field.os`? Why do we have a stargate address and an operating system stored in those fields?

TL;DR: Stop over abbreviating variable names. They make sense to you (now), but will they make sense to Mr. Maintainer? Remember, that poor confused maintainer could be a future version of yourself.

Comment: I do, but in this context I didn't think anyone would care. I think your over analyzing it - what does it matter what that date represents, it is a date.

Comment: Well you know 4 of May is a date, but it's also May the fourth be with you, it can have a meaning. If the variable has a meaning in your method, you should show it in it's name. It's not the end of the world, but with good names everything will be more clear and easier to understand.

Comment: Like I said, this is just an example I need to optimize if poss. not here to fix the naming convention - that comes later.

Comment: I think you should read this [help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) article. I believe your question may be off-topic.

Comment: Then as per the third bullet point this is here for performance so not off topic. If you cannot help with that don't start a battle on something I am not here for. Thanks for your concern, but I have no problems with naming conventions once it becomes embedded code.

Comment: @OneFineDay According to the rules of this site, answers can review any aspect of the code, not just the ones you ask about. One reviewer thinks that your naming can be improved, and judging from the votes, five others agree. I'd suggest that you consider that as valuable feedback. Whether you end up implementing the suggested changes is a private matter for you to decide.

Answer (score 15):

Your throw-away "test code" doesn't need to `Dim` a variable and introduce YACI (Yet Another Cryptic Identifier) - this:

> ```
> Dim sw As New Stopwatch
> sw.Start()
> Dim fd1 As New Field With {.dateTime = Date.Now, .sg = "23:59:00", .os = "00:03:00"}
> Dim fd2 As New Field With {.dateTime = Date.Now, .sg = "00:01:00", .os = "00:03:00"}
> Dim fd3 As New Field With {.dateTime = Date.Now, .sg = "0:00:00", .os = "00:04:00"}
> Dim fd4 As New Field With {.dateTime = Date.Now, .sg = "00:12:00", .os = "00:05:00"}
> Dim fds As New List(Of Field) From {fd1, fd2, fd3, fd4}
> Dim m = GetMinTimeSpan(fds)
> Debug.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.ToString)
> ```

...could be made much easier to *tweak the inputs at will* if you get rid of the identifiers altogether and simply use a *collection initializer* - also declaring, initializing and starting the `Stopwatch` could be a one-liner:

```
Dim sw As Stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew()
Dim testFields As New List(Of Field) From
{
    New Field With {.dateTime = Date.Now, .sg = "23:59:00", .os = "00:03:00"},
    New Field With {.dateTime = Date.Now, .sg = "00:01:00", .os = "00:03:00"},
    New Field With {.dateTime = Date.Now, .sg = "0:00:00", .os = "00:04:00"},
    New Field With {.dateTime = Date.Now, .sg = "00:12:00", .os = "00:05:00"}
}
Dim result = GetMinTimeSpan(testFields)
Debug.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.ToString)
```

Now if I want to add/remove a `Field` to/from the test suite, I can just *do that*.

I realize this is probably throw-away code. The point is, it's code you've written, and that's how you wrote it. I ran it a couple of times, and this is the string representation printed to the *debug output*:

> ```
> 00:00:00.0189976
> 00:00:00.0107947
> 00:00:00.0120666
> 00:00:00.0158479
> 00:00:00.0222599
> ```

So I put the method call in a tight loop, running 10K iterations:

```
    For index = 1 To 10000
        GetMinTimeSpan(fds)
    Next

    Debug.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.ToString)
```

And it printed this:

```
00:00:00.3523980
00:00:00.3053835
00:00:00.3534577
00:00:00.3389172
00:00:00.3423430
```

Just what are you trying to optimize exactly? Have you identified a bottleneck somewhere? I don't see a performance issue with your code at first glance, because it's pretty hard to get a hold of what your code does, at a glance.

Let's see:

> ```
> Private Function GetMinTimeSpan(fds As List(Of Field)) As String
> ```

To me, a function that's called `GetMinTimeSpan` should rightfully return a `TimeSpan`. Yours is returning a `String`, which is potentially somewhat irritating for the maintainer. You're also taking in a `List`, when you only need an `IEnumerable` - why restrict to a `List` when you could just as well work off any possible and not-yet-even-written implementation of the `IEnumerable` interface?

> ```
>    Dim result As New List(Of Date)
> ```

This is another surprise. Given the signature, I'd expect `result` to be a `String` - but no, it's a `List` of ..dates?

> ```
>    Return result.Min.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
> ```

Ah, I see what you're doing. So this loop is traversing the `IEnumerable(Of Field)` into a `List(Of Field)`, so that you can leverage the `IComparable` implementation of `Date` and get the `Min` value in the list, *and then* return its string representation.

Let's see why we even need to explicitly iterate that `IEnumerable` in the first place:

> ```
>     For Each item In fds
>         Dim dt As Date = item.dateTime
>         Dim s1 As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(dt.ToString("HH:mm:ss"))
>         Dim s2 As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(item.sg)
>         Dim s3 As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(item.os)
> ```

My lazy little brain doesn't like having to make associations/mappings between variables and their meaning. Whatever `sg` means, `s2` should be named `sg` to mean the same thing. Same with `s3`, should be called `os`, and `s1` would be `timePortion` or something like that, and then `dt` could be `itemDate`.

---

## **[♠] AVOID 2-letter identifiers [♠]** <sub>(yes, in spades).</sub>

Your naming conventions reflects your coding style, and *that's not something you just "fix later"* - you don't step into a codebase six months down the line and magically remember the context of every cryptic identifier. **Write code as if the person maintaining it was a serial killer that knows where you live.**

More seriously: you should name your identifiers while their meaning is crystal-clear in your brain, *as soon as this meaning is crystalized*, not "later". I cringe at `fd1..fd2..fd3..fd4` in your *throw-away code*, seeing `s1..s2..s3` in *your actual code* make me want to frantically rename everything just to get a freakin' idea of what stands for what.

Naming is important; **writing** code is hardly 20% of the job. The other 80% is spent **reading** code. Might as well make it readable.

---

Back to `s1`.

> ```
> Dim s1 As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(dt.ToString("HH:mm:ss"))
> ```

This is... rather creative. Here's a less convoluted way:

```
Dim itemTime As TimeSpan = itemDate.TimeOfDay 's1
```

Then you have two nested conditions, with very similar branches - what's that smell?

```
result.Add(Date.Parse(itemDate.AddDays(1).ToShortDateString & " " & item.sg))
result.Add(Date.Parse(itemDate.AddDays(1).ToShortDateString & " " & item.os))
result.Add(Date.Parse(itemDate.ToShortDateString & " " & item.sg))
result.Add(Date.Parse(itemDate.ToShortDateString & " " & item.os))
```

Ok several things. Let's simplify a bit. A `Date` has an `Add(TimeSpan)` method that seems to have been written exactly for this:

```
result.Add(itemDate.AddDays(1).Date.Add(item.sg))
result.Add(itemDate.AddDays(1).Date.Add(item.os))
result.Add(itemDate.Date.Add(item.sg))
result.Add(itemDate.Date.Add(item.os))
```

Now here I'm assuming `Field` is a class that you own, too - and whose `sg` and `os` members (which should be `Sg` and `Os`... with an actual meaningful name for Heaven's sake) are of type `TimeSpan`. Your test code seems to indicate that they are of type `String`, which is a bad idea since it's really a `TimeSpan` - the database has it as a string? So what, your code isn't the database. You want your code to call a TimeSpan, a TimeSpan. Perform the parsing when you load the data from the record into your `Field` instance.

Otherwise you need to do this inside your loop, and you're wasting cycles parsing a `TimeSpan` from a `String` that should already be a `TimeSpan` - these two lines could be removed:

```
Dim sg As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(item.sg) 's2
Dim os As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(item.os) 's3
```

If you control the code for `Field`, change the type of `sg` and `os` to `TimeSpan`, and move the parsing earlier, outside of the `GetMinTimeSpan` function.

> ```
> If Not item.sg = nullField Then
> ```

Right. `item.sg` is *nullable*. Don't make it a `TimeSpan` - make it a `TimeSpan?` (or `Nullable(Of TimeSpan)` and make your condition look like this instead:

```
If item.sg.HasValue Then
```

This is the result of all changes so far:

```
Private Function GetMinTimeSpan(fds As IEnumerable(Of Field)) As String
    Dim result As New List(Of Date)
    For Each item In fds
        Dim itemDate As Date = item.dateTime
        Dim itemTime As TimeSpan = itemDate.TimeOfDay

        If item.sg.HasValue Then
            If itemTime > item.sg Then
                result.Add(itemDate.AddDays(1).Date.Add(item.sg))
            Else
                result.Add(itemDate.Date.Add(item.sg))
            End If
        End If
        If itemTime > item.os Then
            result.Add(itemDate.AddDays(1).Date.Add(item.os))
        Else
            result.Add(itemDate.Date.Add(item.os))
        End If
    Next
    Return result.Min.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
End Function
```

---

Not so many changes, it's the same algorithm: you're iterating once (\$O(n)\$) to get every time stamp into `result`. Then `result.Min` iterates again to find the smallest value.

Why not just find the smallest value yourself, and ditch the `List` altogether?

```
Private Function GetMinTimeSpan(fds As IEnumerable(Of Field)) As String

    Dim currentMin As Date = DateTime.MaxValue

    For Each item In fds
        Dim itemDate As Date = item.dateTime
        Dim itemTime As TimeSpan = itemDate.TimeOfDay

        Dim temp As Date
        If item.sg.HasValue Then
            If itemTime > item.sg Then
                temp = itemDate.AddDays(1).Date.Add(item.sg)
                If temp < currentMin Then
                    currentMin = temp
                End If
            Else
                temp = itemDate.Date.Add(item.sg)
                If temp < currentMin Then
                    currentMin = temp
                End If
            End If
        End If
        If itemTime > item.os Then
            temp = itemDate.AddDays(1).Date.Add(item.os)
            If temp < currentMin Then
                currentMin = temp
            End If
        Else
            temp = itemDate.Date.Add(item.os)
            If temp < currentMin Then
                currentMin = temp
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Return currentMin.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
End Function
```

As I proceeded to write this, a doubt arised - have I broken functionality? I hope not! So many questions pop up all of a sudden:

- Why are you only returning the time portion of the smallest date in `result`?
- Why are you returning a `String` representation of that date?
- Why is the method called `GetMinTimeSpan` when it's actually returning a `String` that represents the time portion of a `Date`?
- Is this the desired behavior?

So I ran the code again (with the 10K iterations), and got this output:

```
00:00:00.0273893
00:00:00.0258447
00:00:00.0318047
00:00:00.0276503
00:00:00.0306695
```

For a single call:

```
00:00:00.0027795
00:00:00.0051286
00:00:00.0038952
00:00:00.0033619
00:00:00.0062803
```

Is it faster? Probably. Is it more efficient? Certainly is. Can it be further refactored? Sure! Is this answer long enough? Definitely!

Comment: I feel like I needed a Date due to the issue I stated above. If I only eval the timespan 23:59:00 is not less than 00:01:00, but as a complete date it is.

Comment: I get there is a lot of conversions going on here and that's why I am here for fresh perspective. I am not the best coder, but I get by pretty good all the same.

Comment: You've found the best place to learn and improve! I've learned several things myself while writing this post, too - I'm not very experienced with VB.NET. I might give it a few more rounds of refactoring and see what I get.. and then rewrite it in C# ;)

Answer (score 8):

I don't know how much of an optimization it is, but what really jumps out at me is all the conversions between `TimeSpan`, `DateTime`, and `String`. I'd classify it as "code smell" even if it's not bringing down the performance (though you really should run it through a profiler to be sure). I suspect it would be better to use the built-in methods of `DateTime` and `TimeSpan` in order to convert between them as directly as possible, without roundtripping through `String`.

I also don't understand why you build a `List (Of Date)`. If you're going to compute a minimum, just designate a variable for it, and each time update it if necessary.

Comment: I don't know why you only have 2(3 after me) votes so far. You actually have something intelligent to say about the performance. I like the idea of a variable that holds the lowest and checks each new timespan. Thanks

Comment: That's because what the other people were saying is VERY IMPORTANT. They mentioned actual specific problems with your coding style, and suggested solutions. Listen to them. My suggestions were mostly aesthetic and didn't address the real underlying problems. Also, as I said, I'm not sure if my suggestions will actually improve the runtime.